# How can I intersect values of a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, intersection

For example this is a dictionary

```
dic={3: [2, 7, 8], 1: [7]}
```

I want a list like this [7]

Comment: Make them into sets and use set intersection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get all the values using `.values`, then convert them to set, and get the intersection of them:

```
set.intersection(*list(map(set, dic.values())))
```